# How to architect a Helix solution where features are interdependent

Tags: helix

This is regarding how to plan (or anticipate) and architect the code with `Helix`, where I'm unaware of the project roadmap.
I'm working on a project which has two projects - `Feature.Accounts` and `Feature.Articles`.
`Feature.Accounts` has the `User.cs` class and all the business logic for login, authorization, profile info.
`Feature.Articles` has all the logic restricted to articles only.

Few months into the project, there is now a business requirement like this:

1. A user should be able to select favorite articles.
2. The user's profile page should list their favorite articles.
3. The articles listing page should show/hide articles based on anonymous/logged in/and certain profile properties.

This makes both these Features interdependent. But referencing `Feature.Accounts` into `Feature.Articles` is anti-Helix.

As a temporary solution, I have created two Foundation MVC projects and moved all the business logic and classes into them - `Foundation.Accounts` and `Foundation.Articles`.
Now the feature projects do not have any logic. They only have the `Views`.

But, ideally Foundation projects should only be class libraries and should not have any business logic as that would make them unstable. right?

What should be the correct way to architect this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that according to Helix, Features should be independent of each other. So in your case, you have 2 foundation projects separately, instead, I would suggest creating 1 common Foundation project and moving your common logic into that then referencing this common foundation in your features. And keep your independent logic to the feature itself that is specific to the feature.

**Update** **-**

If you are having common logic that is being used in 3-4 features, you can call it `common.foundation` or `shared.foundation`, and then reference this.

You can keep `ORM` like Glass Mapper in foundation.
You can use Foundation for `Unicorn (Serialization)` - Use Foundation Project to Bootstrap and Set Basic Folder Structure that all other projects are dependent on.

You can have your common `search logic (coveo, solr)` in Foundation.

Follow this for best practices - http://www.mtelligent.com/home/2017/10/13/best-practices-for-sitecore-helix-and-general-development

Foundation should have below as per Helix best practices -

- Projects Reference Each Other as Needed
- Deal with a Suite of templates or Type of Integration
- No Renderings, Layoutsor Web API's.

Sitecore Foundation Framework Tuning Recommended Best Practices

- Remove Projects that aren't desired or would not be wanted to used (don't include everything because it's there, you can add them back easily if you need them).
- Customize Site Configuration and Page Templates to inherit only from the feature templates you want to support.

Comment: What if there is another similar requirement with `PageContent` or `Navigation` where they need `Accounts` logic. Should we keep creating Foundation projects. Also, please tell me what should go into this Foundation project. It should not be having logic...right? Then what should it have. An example related to my question's use case would be helpful.

Comment: "keep your independent logic to the feature itself ". But this is how the Feature project was initially created. Now what was considered as "independent" for that feature is no longer so and needed in other features.

Comment: So you are saying you don't have any logic that is specific to Feature?

Comment: The logic for Articles was to get the list or an articles details. Now both have changed and rely on a user's authentication or profile properties. So, What should go in the Feature & what in Foundation. Also, Shouldn't Foundation be logic free?

Comment: So I think authentication logic should go in Foundation and get Article logic should be in Feature. You can have logic in Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in the case of creating two foundation projects, you should add only one i.e. `Foundation.User` or `Foundation.Authentication` or similar like this. And move the logic that is only common in both of the feature projects.

And you need to refer to this foundation for your feature projects.

This is because, if in the future, you have dependencies between two feature projects then you should not use the same approach. Because this is not the best practice to create a Helix-based solution.

This is the direction you need to keep in mind while creating or modifying any new/existing solution.

**Foundation module**
This acts as an API to Feature modules.
The Foundation does not contain any form of presentation!

**Feature module**
This contains logic and presentation, but never styling.
So the presentation is usually in the form of semantic HTML so it can be styled per the Project module.
Feature modules may reference Foundation modules.

**Project module**
you would typically not include this in a Marketplace package as this is the site-specific stuff, but you could add a demonstration project, for example to explain how the module could be styled.

Hope this makes sense.